# How to access a public function from a model inside a controller in magento?

Tags: php, magento

\
This is a magento issue. I have this controller called ImagesController.php where

```
class My_Sell_ImagesController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
```

I am extending/inhering core controller

Now, I have this another class

```
class My_Advert_Model_Advert extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

public function isValid($arrStepTpCheck){
...
```

I will like to access isValid inside **My_Sell_ImagesController**
maybe something like

```
 $advert = Mage::registry('current_advert');

$arrError = $this->isValid(array('step1'));
```

But this gives me

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method My_Sell_ImagesController::isValid() in .....ImagesController.php
```

I am new to Magento backend. So please help?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
Mage::getModel('advert/advert')->isValid(array('step1'));
```

or

```
My_Advert_Model_Advert::isValid(array('step1'));
```

Comment: Fabulous. Would you mind explanation the code please? As you see I am learning Magento ... what does advert/advert represeting?

Comment: $this is object for the current class or parent class. If you want to call other class function name you can call like this only

Comment: hmm ok.. So I am calling advert class.. and its method.. However, why is it twice.. I mean advert/advert?

Comment: Btw thank you so much. Now I am understanding it so much better.. it is like java :)